# ASP.NET MVC: Map Subdomains to Applications

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dns

I have an app that allows customers to use vanity subdomains for certain resources. E.g.: customerName.domain.com

Currently, all subdomains are handled by the same monolithic application (APP 1), using routes, so I don't have to mess with DNS records.

Now, I want to replicate this monolithic application (APP 1) to another country for compliance reasons, so that the customers of that country will access a copy of that application (APP 2) hosted in that country.

Is there any way to make this new copy of the application handle some of these subdomains without the need to add CNAME records for each customer?

I was thinking something like this:

1- User visits URL customerName.domain.com
2- APP 1 receives that request, does a database lookup and sees that this customer is in another country.
3- APP 1 somehow indicates that the request should be handled by APP 2, permanently.

Since the URL needs to be the same, a typical redirection wouldn't work in this case.

I'm trying to avoid having to create CNAMES for each customer because our DNS provider doesn't have an API, and creating them manually doesn't scale well.

Comment: Unsure how you're _"not messing with DNS records"_ (just) with routing on foo.domain.com,  bar.domain.com...

Comment: @EdSF I'm only using a wildcard A record so all subdomains are pointing to the main IP. And then I use this to route requests to controllers/actions: https://benjii.me/2015/02/subdomain-routing-in-asp-net-mvc/